# Broadcasted row membership between 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose we have the following 2d arrays:

```
>>> A
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1]])

>>> B
array([[2, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 2]])
```

I want to test the membership of the rows of A in the rows of B.
For a single row of A we can test it's membership in B with:

```
np.any(np.all(A[index] == B, axis=1))
```

I want to do this for all rows of A at once without looping over the indices.
The result should be:

```
desired_result = array([False, False, True])
```

How do we retrieve this result in a broadcasted way (without looping over rows of A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected correctly, you can use broadcasting to compare each row of `A` to every row of `B` in a vectorized fashion:

```py
out = (A == B[:, None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)

>>> out
array([False, False,  True])
```

##### Explanation

To better understand how this works, let's use a modified problem:

```py
A = np.array([
    [4, 2],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 1]])

B = np.array([
    [2, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 2]])
```

where we expect to find `A[0]` (`[4, 2]`) at rows 1 and 4 in `B`. Then:

```py
>>> (A == B[:, None]).all(axis=-1)
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False]])
```

Shows that `A[0] == B[1]` and also `A[0] == B[4]` (first column), and that `A[3] == B[3]` (last column).

At this point, just `.any(axis=0)` finishes the job to produce the required result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solution, it works as intended!